# SQL select latest record of particular student with particular status

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please help me to select latest record of each student with status=1. I have a table called `stdData` and columns

```
 Student ID    FDate        Status
     12        2014-03-12      1
     12        2014-03-15      1 
     13        2014-02-03      1 
     13        2014-02-04      0
     13        2014-02-05      1
```

How can I select latest record of each student with status=1?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `group by`

```
select student_id, max(date)
from table_name
where status=1
group by student_id;
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/83159/1)

Answer (score 1):

In this query it is clear that `status = 1` there for i add it in my select, like this:

```
Select Student_ID ,max(Date) Date, 1 status From table1 
where status = 1 Group by Student_ID;
```

### [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/99b29/1)

Answer (score 1):

if you are using sql server then try this

```
Select top(1) * from StudentTable where status =1 order by student_id desc
```

Answer (score 0):

try this !

```
SELECT LAST(column_name) FROM table_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this !

```
;with cte as
(
select *,rn=row_number() over(partition by Student_Id order by Date desc) from #t
)

select * from cte where rn=1 and status=1
```

### <kbd>[SEE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/99b29/3)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

In Sqlserver

```
Create table Student(
ID int identity(1,1) primary key not null,
S_Date datetime,
Status bit
)

insert  into Student values ('2014-03-11',1)
insert  into Student values ('2014-03-12',0)
insert  into Student values ('2014-03-13',1)
insert  into Student values ('2014-03-14',0)
insert  into Student values ('2014-03-15',1)

select top 1 * from Student where Status=1 Order By S_Date Desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` function to achieve this:

```
SELECT Student_ID,  Date , Status
 FROM 
(
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Student_ID ORDER BY Date  DESC) AS rn, Student_ID,  Date , Status
  FROM your_table 
  WHERE Status = 1
) tab
WHERE tab.rn = 1
```